# c#, having issue on stream reading the msbuild log file while msbuild logger is still writing to it

Tags: c#, file-io, streamreader

I try to use StreamReader to read the MSBuild log file real time by using FileSystemWatcher. It always prompt me File Exception when MSBuild is still writing to it. My code may only managed to show the MSBuild log content to my RichTextBox control when MSBuild completed the compilation...

Is there any alternative to write a code for reading a file which is now using by another process? Such as, notepad.exe read file in anytime without concern...

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible, as this is a sharing violation.

Comment: but notepad.exe does the magic.

Comment: How are you opening your StreamReader? Are you specifying to open it in read-only mode? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.openread.aspx

Comment: Okay, well. And i guess you tried to open it with a readonly FileStream? StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

Comment: @trampi, I did what you said before... It still prompted "bla bla filename is used by another process"...

Comment: Try one of the answers. They use one more argument called FileShare - it seems to be what you need. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you instantiating the StreamReader?

If you are simply passing the file path into the constructor then that may be your problem as doing so will not specify the correct file sharing rights.

Try this:

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(File.Open("C:\\......", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use one of the overloads of the 'Open' method, to specify you are only trying to read. Like this:

```
FileStream fs = 
    File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```